# Don't you need to dereference a pointer to do bitwise operations on a register?

Tags: c, pointers, bitwise-operators

In the code below the line `while ((uart[2] & (1<<6)) == 0);` checks if a bit has been set in a hardware register.

My question is - the code creates a pointer `*uart` which points at the address 0x00021000. If you want to `&` in (1<<6) should you not have to dereference the pointer?

```
#define UART_BASE 0x00021000

void putstring(char *str) {

    volatile uint32_t *uart = (volatile uint32_t*) UART_BASE;

    while (1)
    {
        while (*str != '\0')
        {
            while ((uart[2] & (1<<6)) == 0);
            uart[1] = *str;
            str++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing, [ ]

Answer (score 1):

In C, `x[y]` is equivalent to `*(x+y)`.  So you are dereferencing the pointer when you do `uart[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

`uart[2]` is another way of writing `*(uart + 2)`, so it *does* dereference the pointer.